# how to get co-ordinates of pixel by clicking on it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, bitmap, tooltip, pixel

i'm new to C# and .net. i want to get the co-ordinates of the pixel by clicking on it,such that it should display in a tool tip!!i have a code to get the vertex but i donno how to associate with the mouse click.

```
public class Vertex
    {
        public Vertex(int i, int j)
        {
            this.X = i;
            this.Y = j;
        }
         public int X { get; set; }
         public int Y { get; set; }
         public string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("({0}/{1})", this.X, this.Y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: do, u want to get the Mouse Coordinates in Windows Forms or in a aspx page?

Comment: @kalyan.. i want to get the bitmap coordinates(donno whether they are called mouse coordinates or not)  on windows form .there is extended picture box where bitmap is displayed ,i want the popup window(tool tip) to be displayed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `WindowsForms` handle the mouse down event. The msdn page for the [MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.x.aspx) gives an example of displaying the coordinates in a tooltip.

Edit:
Just a note about something to keep in mind. The coordinates in the the `MouseEventArgs` can vary depending on what event you are handling (see the earlier referenced mouse event args msdn page). In some cases the `Location` is relative to the control, in others to the form, and other times the screen.